# wxPython - Plot update on specific parameter change

Tags: python, plot, wxpython, automatic-updates

Dear all passionated programmers,

I am programming an GUI to investigate my data. Those data is displayed in a 3D plot on a panel. The Plot is filling a prepared FigureCanvas on my GUI by the time I hit a Button. The Plot function gathers some parameter information from my Interface and is created.
I want to automate the process by enabling the function to always create a new plot when a parameter is changed.

I am more than helpless right now. Maybe there is something I am missing.
Is there some module that I can use ? Or is there a common way of doing something like that:

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

    self.InitUI()
    self.Show(True)

def InitUI(self):    
    print __doc__
    self.figure1 = Figure(figsize=(1,1))
    self.mft_plot = FigureCanvas(panel, -1, self.figure1)

    self.SpinCtrl_Y = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value="0", size=(60,30), max = 10000) # Y
self.SpinCtrl_times = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value="0",size=(100,30),min=-200, max=500) # time

    btn5 = wx.Button(panel, label = 'Create Vol. Image', pos = ((650), 10),
                     size = (150, 25))
    btn5.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPlotCreation)

def OnPlotCreation(self, e):
    print 'Waiting for time point..'


    t_enter = self.SpinCtrl_times.GetValue()
      # Transform time sample point to dimensional time point ..
    self.t_in_ms0 = t_enter * 1e3

    print 'Seleted time point is: %.2f ms' %self.t_in_ms0

    # Check for a threshold..
    threshold = self.mftthreshold.GetValue()

    self.figure1.clear()
    print 'Plot.'
    plotting.plot_stat_map( index_img( self.img, float(t_enter) ), figure = self.figure1, threshold= threshold, cut_coords=(self.SpinCtrl_Y.GetValue()),
                             annotate=True, title='t=%.2f ms' %self.t_in_ms0 )
```

For an simple example i posted you this, a lil bit long, code sample. The goal I want to achieve is the function automatically runs again after 
`self.mftthreshold` or
`self.SpinCtrl_times` or `self.SpinCtrl_Y` was changed.

I hope anyone can give me a hind on how to make this possible.

Thankful Greetings,
Daniel

Comment: Bind the spin controls using `wx.EVT_SPINCTRL` to `self.OnPlotCreation`. Sadly, you have left key parts out of your code sample so it is difficult to say with real certainty.

Comment: Thank you. It is quite an easy solution. Very pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was:

```
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

    self.InitUI()
    self.Show(True)

def InitUI(self):    
    print __doc__
    self.figure1 = Figure(figsize=(1,1))
    self.mft_plot = FigureCanvas(panel, -1, self.figure1)

    self.SpinCtrl_Y = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value="0", size=(60,30), max = 10000) # Y
    self.SpinCtrl_times = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value="0",size=(100,30),min=-200, max=500) # time

    btn5 = wx.Button(panel, label = 'Create Vol. Image', pos = ((650), 10),
                     size = (150, 25))

    btn5.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPlot)
    ***self.SpinCtrl_times.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL , self.OnPlot)***

def OnPlotCreation(self, e):
    print 'Waiting for time point..'


    t_enter = self.SpinCtrl_times.GetValue()
      # Transform time sample point to dimensional time point ..
    self.t_in_ms0 = t_enter * 1e3

    print 'Seleted time point is: %.2f ms' %self.t_in_ms0

    # Check for a threshold..
    threshold = self.mftthreshold.GetValue()

    self.figure1.clear()
    print 'Plot.'
    plotting.plot_stat_map( index_img( self.img, float(t_enter) ), figure = self.figure1, threshold= threshold, cut_coords=(self.SpinCtrl_Y.GetValue()),
                             annotate=True, title='t=%.2f ms' %self.t_in_ms0 )
```

Thank you for the help Rolf of Saxony.